# Javascript/Ajax/Json: Sending objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a form where people enter their clients into.

This form allows the user to add as many phone numbers, emails, and addresses as they want.

Phone and email have type and data fields for each added row `(phone_type, phone_data)` while Address has type, street, city, state, and zip fields for each row `(address_type, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip)`.

So for example, when the user adds a phone field it adds:

```
<input type="text" name="phone_type[]" />
<input type="text" name="phone_data[]" />
```

I need to send the form data over Ajax to a PHP to process and store in database.

I've thought of storing it in array within an object.

```
phone = new Object();
var phone.data = new Array(), 
phone.type = new Array();
$("input[name='phone_data[]']").each(function() {
  if($(this).val() != '') {
  phone.data.push($(this).val());
  phone.type.push($('select[name="phone_type[]"]').val());
})
```

This doesn't seem to work. Am I even approaching this correctly?

Also, once I get it into an object that I send over Ajax to a PHP page, how do I grab the values?

Comment: by the way phone_type[] is not a select tag. Maybe that is causing a 'undefined' exception

Comment: What do you mean phone_type[] is not a select tag? It's on an input. It's a dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

serialize your form... use `data` of ajax to sent the serialize data to the server...

```
 data:$('#YourFORMID').serialize();
```

here is the documentaiotn have alook to the examples...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

and to grab the data in your PHP (if you are using ajax type as post)

```
 $data=$_POST['phone_data'];
 $type=$_POST['phone_type'];
```

if `ajax type : GET`

```
 $data=$_GET['phone_data'];
 $type=$_GET['phone_type'];
```

Comment: Similar to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019608/pass-entire-form-as-data-in-jquery-ajax-function

Comment: if that is an answer thn.. you post it as an answer.... not as comment.... and if you want to post this as comment, you can use add comment in the question...

Comment: If I send the data that way how would I go about grabbing the data in PHP the page it is sent to?

Comment: if u r posting the data thn use..$_POST['inputname']

Comment: I did actually post it as an answer originally but SO said it was "trivial" and added it as a comment. Took me a few tries before I figured out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to reinvent jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
var frm = $("#myForm");
var values = frm.serialize();

//make Ajax call
$.post("someUrl", values, function(){} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZcja/

Answer (score 1):

You can most definitely use jQuery `serialize()`. In your event which triggers the processing you can do the following:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "your_php_processing_page.php",  
    data: $("#FormID").serialize(),  
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(data){
        // do stuff here
    },  
    error: function() {  
        // do stuff here             
    }  
});
```

In `your_php_processing_page.php` you can get the values as follows:

```
$phone_types = $_POST["phone_type"];
$phone_data = $_POST["phone_data"];
```

Comment: Thanks for summing it up. You also helped me realize a better way to send over ajax. One more question though. I have phone_type[] and phone_data[] 'linked' meaning that I need to get data of the ones next to each other because they were meant to be together. How do I know how which one goes with which in PHP?