# Open JS pop-up when Submit is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a contact form on my web site included where visitors have to fill in their name, address and email and now I try to add a content locker (javascript) which shall appear once they click on the "submit" button. The "onclick" works but the site automatically moves forward to the "submit.php" site and closes the content locker in seconds. I also want to have the visitors data already saved in case they close the site without paying attention to the PopUp. Is this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried delaying the submission?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    form.submit();
                }, 3000); // in milliseconds
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I actually want the site only then to be forwarded, when they have unlocked the locker.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using AJAX?

use JQuery to lock the data in the form and send all the data to your submit.php with

```
<script>
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
var data = $('form').serialize();
$.post('url', data, function(){
 // do something when done saving
});
</script>
```

Information given from this answer: [Pass entire form as data in jQuery Ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019608/pass-entire-form-as-data-in-jquery-ajax-function)

Comment: Could you eventually please take a look on this via Skype?

Comment: sorry, im not able to skype, but could you paste some sourcecode?
it would help if you can paste submit.php sourcecode and the form-sourcecode

Comment: The source code is very large, it's really an usual contact form where I want to let a content lock appear once the "submit" is clicked.