# How to retrieve form elements with React's ref?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

My task is to upload an image and update the user table without the page being refreshed. My search suggested to grab the form elements with `refs` but I'm getting, in console:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
>
> app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `user_params'
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3:in`update'

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'welcome#index'
  resources :users do
    member do
      post 'upload' => 'users#update'
    end
  end
end
```

**The app:**

```
var User = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function(){
    // Trying so see what this shows in the browser console
    var foo = $(this.refs.myForm).elements;
    console.log(foo);
  }.bind(this),

  onUpload: function(){
    var formData = $(this.refs.myForm).serialize();
    $.ajax({
       url: '/users/1/upload',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
           console.log("success: " + data);
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("error in ajax form submission");
       }
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form ref="myForm" remote="true">
          <input type="file" name="user[avatar]" />
        </form>
         {/* Placing the button outside the form prevents a refresh */}
        <button className="button" onClick={this.onUpload}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
module.exports = User;
```

**User Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    User.find(1).update_attributes(user_params)
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
    end
end
```

I've see that, on the web, other people used `this.refs.myForm.elements` so what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<input type="file" name="user[avatar]" />
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="user" />

remove bind(this) from componentDidMount
```

change

```
  componentDidMount: function(){
    // Trying so see what this shows in the browser console
    var foo = $(this.refs.myForm).elements;
    console.log(foo);
  }.bind(this),
```

to

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    // Trying so see what this shows in the browser console
    var foo = $(this.refs.myForm).elements;
    console.log(foo);
  },
```

Comment: No. It must be like this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html My `ref` is undefined anywhere I place it.

Comment: can u check what the value of $(this.refs.myForm).serialize();
in the console .

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myForm' of undefined

Comment: strange this.refs should contain myForm

Comment: I know. Placing a ref on the button is the same. This is just a new rails 5 app with nothing else. `rails _5.0.0.rc1_ new demo --database=postgresql`

Comment: remove bind(this) componentDidMount , you should  not bind componentDidMount , that why this was undefined in componentDidMount

Comment: That function was to mess with. Deleting it makes no difference.

Comment: if your bind this then babel transpiler is messing up this , making it undefined checked in codepen

Comment: Oh! It's removed and in browser console it's showing blank: nothing. Just a white space. In the render it's showing as `undefined`

Comment: $(this.refs.myForm) isnt jquery element now

Comment: Lets sort this first: my ref is not working at all. Ive adding an input field with `ref="test"` and `this.refs.test` shows blank in the console. Weird.

Comment: for input files jquery serialize I have checked . this.refs.test should work
have used it 1000 times
console.log(this.refs)
I used your code in codepen I am seeing the refs

Comment: Weird. Other project `refs` work. See my full code: https://github.com/SylarRuby/react_ajax_upload

Comment: Ok. Updated to react 15.1.0 and refs now works. What's the correct way for: `$(this.refs.myForm).serialize();`?

Comment: this is the correct way. but it wont give you input file .For the file stuff 
follow this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: `var foo = $(this.refs.myForm).elements;` is undefined. `var foo = $(this.refs.myForm).context;` gives me the html-like syntax in the console. How to serialize that so rails sees the params?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thanks for your help, Piyush, for your time and effort. You have given me clues of what to search for. Moh Arjmandi has the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019608/pass-entire-form-as-data-in-jquery-ajax-function).

To rewire my function:

```
onUpload: function(){
    var fd = $(this.refs.myForm).context;
    var formData = new FormData(fd);
    $.ajax({
       url: '/users/1/upload',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
           console.log("success: " + data);
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("error in ajax form submission");
       }
    });
  },
```

Quoted by [Moh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3097216/moh-arjmandi):

> serialize() is not a good idea if you want to send a form with post method. For example if you want to pass a file via ajax its not gonna work.

And the complete app [here](https://github.com/SylarRuby/react_ajax_upload).