# Java Servlet request.getParameter is null

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, servlets

I want to use request.getparameter to determine the action for an event for my page. Example Add or Delete button.

But when I have the button to onsubmit="post();return false;" the Javascript for an ajax to return a content-type application/json the request.get parameter is always null.

When I remove the the onsubmit method I will get the request parameter equal "add".

In this case how should I determine the action so that I can have different button on the page.

```
JavaScript
function post() {
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("postView").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
            //Do someting
    xhttp.open("POST", "myServlet", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(jsonObj);
}

HTML Form
<form name="myForm" action="myServlet" method="post" onsubmit="post();return false;">
Name: <input type="text" id="fnText">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
</form>


Java Servlet
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
System.out.println("Method "+request.getMethod());           
String add = request.getParameter("add");
System.out.println("getParameter is " + add);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting the value of jsonObj, you need to pass it, otherwise you will receive no values.

here is an example of what you should send:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/myServlet");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"add":"add"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send the request through the ajax call (i.e. using the `post()` function), you are not passing the values for the form.

When you remove the `onsubmit` method, you are using the action of the form and the form is getting encoded and sent in the http request.

**Note**: You should consider using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), then your javascript code will be much simplified.

See this post: [Pass entire form as data in jQuery Ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019608/pass-entire-form-as-data-in-jquery-ajax-function)