# How do I use jQuery Post/Ajax instead of form submit?

Tags: jquery

I have a form to submit and once submitted I need to display the confirmation page with form details. I used an below code to do that, However, it is redirected to blank page.

**Code:**

Previous submit action which needs to jQuery Post

```
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        confirmationPage();
        document.formPsmq.action = "/reports/htm/submit.do";
        document.formPsmq.submit();
    });
```

How to use jQuery post method to stay on the same page without redirection?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why down voted?

Comment: You can use `window.location.href = path` on AJAX success paramter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies. Now I am understood "Why this question was downvoted". I didn't perform a basic search to find the answer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019608/pass-entire-form-as-data-in-jquery-ajax-function) post helped me.

Here is the code

```
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        confirmationPage();
        //document.formPsmq.action = "/reports/htm/submit.do";
        //document.formPsmq.submit();
        var data = $('#formPsmq').serialize();
        $.post('/reports/htm/submit.do', data);
    });
```