# JQuery serialize() not sending parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

**html:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" autocomplete="off" action="" method="POST" name="formular_comanda" id="formular_comanda">

<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="inaltime_best" id="inaltime_best" placeholder="H (mm)" required="required" onchange="calculator_piese()" />

</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function calculator_piese() {
  var height = document.getElementById("inaltime_best");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "calculator/panouri-simple/calcul-panouri-simple.php",
    data: $("#formular_comanda").serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      document.getElementById("show_panels").innerHTML = result;
      console.log(height.value); // this return my input value
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log("Eroare:");
      console.log(result);
      console.log();
    }
  });
}
```

**calcul-panouri-simple.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$height = $_POST['height'];
var_dump($height); //this returns NULL
```

I have a problem. My php returns error:

> Notice: Undefined index: height in ... calcul-panouri-simple.php on line 3

`console.log(height.value)` returns me the value, but from php `var_dump` i get `NULL`.

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: It's because height is not part of your form - you can add it to the end like this: `$("#formular_comanda").serialize() + '&height=' + height`

Comment: But it is between form tags. What do you mean is not part of my form?

Comment: It's not an input on your form - you just set it as a variable from the input called `inaltime_best`, if you do not want to do the above, then just use `$_POST['inaltime_best']`

Comment: `var height` not `POST` via `ajax` because you wrote it before `ajax call`

Comment: have you tried using `FormData`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27774479/1732775

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? The input name is `inaltime_best`, while you're trying to get a value from `height` :)

Comment: @Roomy Indeed you are right.

Comment: @Pete you are also right. I thought the index from POST should be the one I mention in js, like var height = document... but it turns out that POST value takes value directly from form through serialize().

Answer (score 0):

```
Because height field is not in your form so you can be use 

function calculator_piese() {
  var height = document.getElementById("inaltime_best");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "calculator/panouri-simple/calcul-panouri-simple.php",
    data: $("#formular_comanda").serialize() + '&height=' + height,
    success: function(result) {
      document.getElementById("show_panels").innerHTML = result;
      console.log(height.value); // this return my input value
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log("Eroare:");
      console.log(result);
      console.log();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: but the height field **IS** inside the form :)

Comment: The problem is i have 40 inputs. why i use serialize in first place? to stop add variables manually.